# How can I change the \ character in a string to the / character?

Tags: c, string, build, special-characters

I'm using GetFullPathName and WinExec.

For WinExec to call my external program properly I need to have a full path to the program.

GetFullPathName() returns the following...

```
C:\job\curr01\help\hlp.exe
```

When I use this path in WinExec, nothing happens.  This is because WinExec is expecting...

```
C:/job/curr01/help/hlp.exe
```

I know this because if I hard code the string "C:/job/curr01/help/hlp.exe" into WinExec() it works just fine and opens the program.

My question is how can I scan my string for '\' and replace them with '/'?

'\' I a special character and the following does not work...

below helpPath = 'C:\job\curr01\help\hlp.exe'

```
for (char* p = helpPath; p = strchr(p, "\"); ++p) {
  *p = "/";
 }
```

C has a problem with "\" because its a special character.  I tried ""\"" and "//" but nothing seems to work.

Comment: this is the opposite of what I want though.  Checking for \ ad replacing with /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (*p == '\\') //Escape the character '\'
    *p = '/';
```

Comment: Awesome works great.  Still doesn't open the file correctly because its adding /Program/Bin into the path after curr01 now, but that's another problem haha.  Thanks

Comment: Nice, can you valid the answer to set the post as solved ? Good luck for your problem, if you can't solve it, post a question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `WinExec` really expects "/" as a directory separator. I believe the "preferred" separator in Win32 API calls is still a "\". Support for the "/" was added to some Win32 API functions some time back, either to make life easier for people familiar with, well, anything except Windows, or to avoid the problems caused by the use of "\" in C string literals. Or maybe for some other reason that only Microsoft understands.

At any rate, you should fix the escaping effect of "\", probably just by doubling it: `c:\\path\\to\\my\\exe`. This is a more Windows-y way of fixing the problem than using forward-slashes, which (IIRC) will work in some places but not in others.

I appreciate that this is not really a new answer, but I note that you have asked other questions where you seem to have similar problems with Windows paths.